# Sentences without and with auxiliary

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> a) Doctor said two kids choked to death due to inhalation of mud.
>
> b) Doctor said two kids were choked to death due to inhalation of mud.

According to me **b)** is more Correct as we should use auxiliary before verb.

Comment: Why do you think the auxiliary is needed?  Update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Only (A) is correct.

> a) The doctor said two kids choked to death due to inhalation of mud.
>
> b) The doctor said two kids were choked to death due to inhalation of mud.

Forget the rest of the sentence, just consider the part with/without the auxiliary:

> Two kids choked
>
> Two kids were choked

"Two kids choked" means that they *involuntarily* choked - perhaps on food, or something else that blocked their windpipe.

"Two kids *were* choked" means something or maybe somebody choked them. If you include this auxiliary verb you need to say what, or who choked them, using "*by*" for example:

> Two kids were choked *by* food.

Only when you omit the auxilary verb can you use "on" and say:

> Two kids choked *on* their food.

Your example uses "*due to*", so it is citing a *cause*, not necessarily the item that they choked on. Consider this example:

> Two children were choked *by* food *due to* not chewing it properly.

In this example, the direct cause of the choking was still the food, but the underlying cause was that the food was unchewed. Only sentence (a) makes sense because it links the cause to the effect.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Both are valid phrases.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Gramatically they both scan, but the latter is misleading and illogical for the reasons I explain.

Comment: This is a good answer. Sentence B is at best infelicitous (pragmatically or semantically anomalous). There is an unlikely interpretation in which the kids were choked by someone because they inhaled mud (some sort of punishment I suppose), which would make the sentence completely fine, if that were the intended meaning.

Comment: Yes, except, The doctor. Basically, were choked to death by someone or something, versus choked to death on food.

Comment: @Lambie This may be explained away by the phenomenon called left-edge deletion, a well-documented feature of spoken English and some variants / registers of written English. See, e.g. https://awweir.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/tallinn-handout-weir.pdf. But in principle you're right.

Comment: No context is provided as to which sentence carries the correct meaning.  Both are grammatically correct.  The answer to the question asked is both.

Answer (score 0):

When *be* is used as an auxillary verb, it can be followed by past participle to form *passive voice*, or present participle to form *progressive* or *continuous* aspect.

Some verbs have a built-in passive meaning or can be used passively without the auxillary.

---

*Choke* can mean either:

- causing a state of restricted flow - *choke* in this case will take an object.
- being in a state of restricted flow - *choke* in this case will not take an object but might be followed by an *on X* that identifies what is restricting the state.

So *X chokes*, and *X chokes on Y* are valid for the second meaning, and *X chokes Y* is valid for the first meaning.

Since the second meaning is already "passive", you can't use passive voice with it.

> I choked on my food but was saved by a helpful person (OK).
>
> I was choked on my food but was saved by a helpful person (incorrect).
>
> The mugger choked the victim nearly to death (OK).
>
> The victim was choked by the mugger nearly to death (OK).

Continuous is OK with the second meaning of *choke*:

> I was choking on my food when a helpful person saved me (OK).

Answer (score -1):

One is active, one is passive. Both are correct.

But I prefer active language as the meaning is usually clearer. As someone mentioned, it could mean someone choked the kids with mud, but I am fairly sure that is not what it means. The first version, the active version, is much clearer. This is because 1) it uses less words, and 2) because active sentences do not separate objects from their actions.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what is the active voice for two *persons were killed in accident*

Comment: Two people died in an accident.

Comment: @user4084 Also, "Doctor said" is incorrect here. it should be "The doctor said or "A doctor said" or "Doctor X said" if the name is known. If the name is omitted, an article is needed. Similarly, it should be **an** accident, not 'killed in accident", again an article is needed.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Some people call their doctors "Doctor." It could be an affectionate name, or something like that!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Not really - when people call a doctor "Doctor", they are using it as a form of *address*, like "Sir", or "Madam". You wouldn't use it in isolation to *refer* to them.

Comment: @Astralbee -- You very much could. It's not necessarily in the form of an address.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I can't imagine it being used, not going to argue that it can't ever, but how long would answers be if we went off at every possible tangent?